# How to replace special character in a arrayadapter string?

Tags: java, android

I am getting the title from an RSS feed and displaying it using an array adapter. How can I replace a special character with an empty space? Can anyone help on this?

```
ArrayAdapter<String> itemList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.cricketlist, item);
```

Comment: What is your special character?

Comment: This is my special character    &quot;

Comment: @sravanthi you don't need to specify android in question title as this is handled by the tag

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `str` is your `String`.

```
str = str.replace("&quot;", " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [String.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)  and  [String.replace(char oldChar, char newChar)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for relpacing chars from string

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 str = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+"," ")
```

Also

```
public string deleteSpecialChar(string text)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            var lastWasInvalid = false;
            for(int i=0;i<text.length();i++)
            {
                if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(text.charAt(i)))
                {
                    sb.Append(c);
                    lastWasInvalid = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!lastWasInvalid)
                        sb.Append(" ");
                    lastWasInvalid = true;
                }
            }

            return sb.ToString().Trim();

        }
```